# Multiline Header/Footer?

Tags: tables, header-footer

Using LaTeX, I'm trying to make a multi-line header (using `\markright`), and having a somewhat difficult time doing it.

I've tried:

1. Putting a table within the header using
   `\markright{\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}}`
   This gives me an error: `Paragraph ends before \reserved@a was complete`.
2. Simply inserting the newline with `\\`
   This simplys crams everything on the same line, the exact same was as if  there 
   were no `\\`'s

Is there a "proper" way to do this in LaTeX using `fancyhdr`, or is there some sort of dark magic involved here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note that `\markright` has moving arguments, you should use:

```
\markright{\protect\parbox[b]{2cm}{foo\\bar}}
```

A `\parbox` or `minipage` is OK. But if you want to protect `tabular`, you can use:

```
\newcommand\headingtable{%
  \begin{tabular}[b]{l}foo\\bar\end{tabular}}
\markright{\protect\headingtable}
```

or (with fewer restrictions)

```
\newsavebox{\headingbox}
\sbox{\headingbox}{%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{5cm}
  foo\par bar
  \end{minipage}}
\markright{\usebox{\headingbox}}
```

Further reading:

https://texfaq.org/FAQ-protect

[What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands? When and why do we need \protect?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands)

Comment: Good information - I saw something on `tabular` being `fragile`, but had no idea it applied here. Thanks for the quick response.